# Page Breaks in Microsoft SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working with SSRS 2008 or 2014 and SQL Server 2014. One of the issues the team is having is around the formatting of the SSRS report. The goal is to have the report data format to render in an user friendly format. Unfortunately, a requirement is that the report uses two tables that can display 1:x number of records. As you can imagine, all data fields under the tables will now be pushed further down the page.

My question is, has anyone encountered this type of scenario and have an SSRS code-based solution to handle the formatting of the report?

Comment: Can you show us some screenshot of your result and your design, it will give more idea about your problem and what do you mean by 1:x no of records?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to display a 1 to many relationship in the report but want to keep the first table's results together.  Maybe what you need is a drilldown/drillthrough  report; this is available without a code-based solution.

This article explains the concept
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/drilldown-action-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2014

There are many Youtube videos on how to set up drilldown reports, here is one example
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C56fMnp4oaA